# Categorical construction of polynomial functors; how do we go from C to its slice?

Tags: ct.category-theory, slice-categories

In [Predicative toposes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.0959.pdf), van den Berg, defines a polynomial functor as follows:

Let f : B → A be a map in a locally cartesian closed category C. The polynomial
functor associated to f is the endofunctor;
$P_f : C \xrightarrow{B \: \times \: -} C / B \xrightarrow{\Pi_f} C / A \xrightarrow{\Sigma_A} C$.
I think I understand how to explicitly define every one of these functors, except for the $B \: \times \: -$.

I thought I would define it as the functor $C / \top \xrightarrow{\Pi_!} C / A$, but that would require existence of a terminal object, which if I understand correctly is not required for locally cartesian closed categories and I am not even sure it would be correct in presence of these.
How do we define the functor $B \: \times \: -$?

Comment: Definition 2.8 in this paper states that all locally cartesian closed categories have finite limits, so they do have terminal objects. The functor $B \times -$ is the pullback functor induced by the unique map $B \to \mathbf{1}$.

Comment: that is indeed the case and i completely missed it, this answers my confusion.

Comment: Even without a terminal object, you could define $B\times-$ as soon as you have binary products. On objects, it sends any $X$ in $C$ to the projection $B\times X\to B$ in $C/B$. On morphisms, it sends $f:X\to Y$ to $1_B\times f:B\times X\to B\times Y$. You need $\top$ only if you want to call  $B\times-$ a pullback functor.

Comment: @AndreasBlass do all LCCCs have binary products even without having a terminal objects?

Comment: This was answered in the first comment here (which should actually be posted as an answer, by the way).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg LCCCs in the paper have terminal object, now Andreas Blass said:
"Even without a terminal object, you could define B×− as soon as you have binary products." So I am asking if these LCCCs without terminal object (in style of nlab LCCCs) have binary products?

Comment: No, they do not. For example, consider the category of all topological spaces and _local homeomorphisms_. This is a category with pullbacks and every slice is cartesian closed (indeed, a topos) but not itself cartesian closed.